# convert to ISO dateTime in java

Tags: java, datetime

```
 I have to convert String "15-08-2021" to  DateTime  yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'
```

'''
Tried the following way,which didnt work.

```
    String toDateString= "15-08-2021";
    DateTime dt= new DateTime(toDateString);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
     DateTime result=formatter.parse(dt);
```

Comment: Java can't just look in a crystal ball and figure out you want `22:01:00`. You'd have to supply that information, obviously.

Comment: Please stop using `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: @rzwitserloot just gave that as a example, i want that particular ISO format that's all.Thanks!

Comment: You can't have that ISO format without some source of what time you want.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Or if you are already using Joda-Time (this is not clear), you may use the like-named class from that library.

Comment: Which `DateTime` class is that (if an existing one)? `org.joda.time.DateTime`??

Comment: @BaruReddy - I saw you posted this question (which has been deleted by voting now) again today. In fact, you had posted two questions in that. Since you are new to SO, I would like to inform you that you should not club different requirements in a single question; keep your question focussed on one problem. Also, whenever someone writes an answer, do comment if you need something more/different from the solution. These things help keep the quality of this website high.

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("15-08-2021", dtfInput);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // Custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formatted = dtfOutput.format(zdt);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-08-15T00:00Z[UTC]
2021-08-15T00:00:00Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/0avttR)

**Note**: In case, you need the time to be different, you can do it in the following way while keeping other things as they are:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.parse("15-08-2021", dtfInput), LocalTime.of(21, 0));
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

**Output:**

```
2021-08-15T21:00Z
2021-08-15T21:00:00Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/EteY12)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Joda-Time? You may consider upgrading to java.time, the modern Java date and time API (you certainly don’t want to downgrade to `SimpleDateFormat` and the other troublesome date and time classes from Java 1.0 and 1.1).

### Using Joda-Time

With Joda-Time I would declare a formatter like this for parsing:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_PARSER =
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")
            .withZoneUTC();
```

Then the conversion goes like this:

```
    String toDateString = "15-08-2021";
    DateTime dt = DateTime.parse(toDateString, DATE_PARSER);
    System.out.println(dt);
```

Output:

> 2021-08-15T00:00:00.000Z

Output includes three decimals on the seconds. It may not be a problem. The output agrees with the ISO 8601 standard that I think you intended to refer to.. If you need to get rid of them, you need a second formatter, but fortunately it’s built in:

```
    String formattedDt = dt.toString(ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis());
    System.out.println(formattedDt);
```

> 2021-08-15T00:00:00Z

### Consider java.time

From the Joda-Time home page:

> Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project.
> No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate
> to `java.time` (JSR-310).

For this option see the good answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash.

### What went wrong in your code?

It seems you confused the concepts of *formatting* and *parsing*. You tried the `parse` method of `SimpleDateFormat`. In its day it was used for converting a `String` in a predefined format into a `Date` (another long outdated class). I am guessing that you want approximately the opposite: the formatting of a `DateTime` into a string in predefined format. Your other issue is that `SimpleDateFormat` never was able to handle Joda-Time `DateTime` objects (or any other class by the same name).

### Links

- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Joda-Time - Home](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Comment: This is a good addition! Many developers are still using Joda Date-Time API (though it is recommended to [write new code or even upgrade the existing code to using `java.time`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/index.html))